# Can mutual fund prices have opening gaps? Might my order to be filled at a higher price?

Tags: investing, mutual-funds, markets, price

My broker offers limit orders on mutual funds. I was curious if mutual funds have open gaps like stocks do. If I want to buy a fund if it goes up to a certain price, would it be safe to set a limit to buy above the current price? I'm afraid the price could gap up overnight causing my order to be filled a higher price.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mutual funds don't work like stocks in that way. The price of a mutual fund is set at the end of each day and doesn't fluctuate during the day. So no matter when you put in your order, it will be filled at the end of the day at whatever the closing price is for that day.

Here is some good information on that

> There is no continuous pricing of fund shares throughout the trading
>   day. When an investor places an order to buy or sell a fund's shares,
>   the order is executed based on the NAV calculated at the end of that
>   trading day, regardless of what time during the day the order was
>   placed. On the other hand, if the investor were to check the price of
>   his or her fund shares halfway through the business day, the price
>   quoted would be the previous day's NAV because that was the last time
>   the fund calculated and reported the value.

-http://www.finweb.com/investing/how-mutual-funds-are-priced.html